# convergence $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{4n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Question: Find the respective Taylor series about $x_0=0$ , and its region of converges:

$$f(x)=\cos(x^2 )-x\cdot \sin(x).$$

I found the series:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{4n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Now I can't find the region of converges.
When I sum them up, it doesn't really help me. I am trying to separate the $x^n$ so I can find the convergence. Any ideas?

Comment: What does it mean *to find the convergence*? You mean the *radius of convergence*? Both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are entire functions, so it is $\cos(x^2)-x\sin(x)$ too. The radius of convergence is $+\infty$.

Comment: What do you mean with 'find the convergence'? What exactly are you trying to find? $f$ is given by a formula that is well-defined for any $x$.

Comment: I found the Taylor series, and now I'm looking for the region of convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the definition, let's try using what you gave us. We have that

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\,x^n$$

where

\begin{equation}
a_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
0&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
-\frac{1}{(4k+1)!}&\text{if $n=4k+2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}+\frac{1}{(4k-1)!}&\text{if $n=4k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Can you see that

$$|a_{2n}|\leq \frac{2}{n!}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Can you conclude using, for instance, the root test?